# How to post (in angular 6) an image to a Web Api 2?

Tags: arrays, angular, image, binary, asp.net-web-api2

I need to send, from an Angular 6 website, an image (a logo), to a webApi . Actually my endpoint is 'touched' by the angular client. So it

From angular I want to send the binary of an image and receive it into a web api Controller. How can I achieve that ? 
 (I am really not good managing image ... )
Is a binary (the File class in angular), is the same a byte[] in webApi ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post  some code that you have tried

Comment: Its just byte[]. You can post it the same way sending any kind of file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way

**Html code**

```
  <input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput>
  <button (click)="fileInput.click()">Select File</button>
  <button (click)="onUpload()">Upload!</button>
```

**Ts code**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class MyFileUploadComponent {
  selectedFile: File;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0]
  }

  onUpload() {

    // make sure you have injected HttpClientModule in app.module.ts

    this.http.post('my-backend.com/file-upload', this.selectedFile)
    .subscribe(... something here..);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Joel , I know that...i ve read it already in other questions but my question is how from a File type (in Angular) can I endup with a byte[] in my controller ....